# Viewpoint coordinates

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to set the 3D viewport coordinates directly? I find I spend a lot of time fighting with the viewpoint and would rather type in some values.

Comment: Are you refering to setting different views while using blender? Front, right, Left, Top, etc?

Comment: Yes, but mainly the User Pers.

Comment: Why not store it as Camera objects? That is their intended purpose after all.

Comment: I'm building a model for a game, not a scene to render. Adding camera objects may interfere with the conversion to other non-Blender formats.

Comment: I don't see how. At worst you would get a few unwanted Camera objects after export that you could delete, which can easily be avoided by not exporting them in the first place (use export selection only, untick cameras, hide them, move them to another layer, or scene). Other than that you could probably use python scripting to save and load a few preset coordinates, there may even be scripts around that do this already.